# Why Does Java's Queue Implement Collection and Iterable?

Tags: java, interface

I've just been reading through Java's documentation, and I'm wondering why [their Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implements both [their Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [their Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interfaces. Collection already implements the Iterable interface, so all of the abstract methods should pass through the Collection interface and reach the Queue Interface. What am I missing about their design here?

Comment: the actual hierarchy is `Queue` extends `Collection` extends `Iterable`

Comment: Right, looking through the source code shows that. But then why do they have it listed as 2 super interfaces? Is it just to make clear that Collection extends Iterable?

Comment: Yes, they simply list all the inherited interfaces as well. Can be very useful, especially in a large class hierarchy where the interface you're interested in is implemented 5 steps away.

Comment: Ah, I get it then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. The [Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html) enumerates **all** of the implemented interfaces.

Comment: Could you clarify what that means in this regard? Why would that mean they want to implement Iterable twice?

Comment: The documentation tool **documents** all of the interfaces the class implements. Even if it is through inheritance.